# SCRIPT COLUNADO (LADO A LADO)

Tags: oracle

boa tarde!
Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho este script abaixo (ORACLE), preciso que os resultados sejam retornados em colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT  
 a.nr_prescricao,
 substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
 decode(a.ie_exame_bloqueado,'S','Bloqueado',
 decode(a.ie_exame_bloqueado,'R','Repetição',
 decode(obter_se_recoleta_proc_etapa(a.nr_prescricao,a.nr_seq_prescricao,a.nr_sequencia),'S','Recoleta',''))) ds_exame_bloqueado,
 a.nr_seq_prescricao,
 a.nm_usuario,
 to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) dt_atualizacao,
 b.ds_usuario,
 substr(obter_ds_motivo_alt_status(nr_seq_motivo_alt_status),1,255) ds_motivo_alteracao_status 
FROM    
    prescr_proc_etapa a,
    usuario b
WHERE  
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  nr_prescricao = 83011
and  nr_seq_prescricao = 1
ORDER BY a.nr_sequencia
```

É possível? Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: A princípio eu vejo que seu select retorna várias colunas (a.nr_prescricao, ds_status, etc). Talvez se você explicasse melhor o que deseja (um exemplo poderia ser esclarecedor) poderia obter ajuda.

Comment: Sim,
São 5 status (Solicitação liberada, Coletado, Recebido Lab, Digitação do resultado, Aprovação do resultado, Liberação do exame) da mesma prescrição (a.nr_prescricao), preciso que saia em coluna (lado a lado), não como na imagem abaixo um do outro.

Comment: Pesquise pela função de agregação LISTAGG juntamente com a cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/pivot-and-unpivot-feature-oracle-db.html    https://glufke.net/oracle/viewtopic.php?t=9819   "pivot" pode ser pelo próprio pivot ou por "case" veja os exemplos.

Comment: Utilizando o LISTAGG, mesmo assim não agrupou ...


SELECT  

e.nm_paciente,
LISTAGG (substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ||' - '|| to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')),';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.ie_etapa, a.dt_atualizacao) A
 
FROM 
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m

Comment: WHERE  

upper(a.nm_usuario)       = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao      = 85724
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1

-- and ie_etapa = 10

and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica

GROUP BY
e.nm_paciente, a.dt_atualizacao

ORDER BY 
e.nm_paciente, a.dt_atualizacao

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
Fiz de uma maneira diferente e deu certo.

Agradeço

select

solic_lib.nm_paciente,
solic_lib.ds_idade,
solic_lib.ds_sexo,
solic_lib.NR_PRONTUARIO,
solic_lib.DS_ANOS_MESES,
solic_lib.DT_NASCIMENTO,
solic_lib.nr_prescricao,
solic_lib.nr_atendimento,
solic_lib.ds_tipo_atendimento,
solic_lib.ds_convenio,
solic_lib.dt_entrada,
solic_lib.npp data_prescricao,
solic_lib.nm_unidade,
solic_lib.ds_setor_atendimento,
solic_lib.nr_crm,
solic_lib.nm_medico,
solic_lib.nm_EXAME,
ap_res.ds_exame_bloqueado STATUS_EXAME,
ap_res.ds_motivo_recoleta,
solic_lib.TUBETE,

solic_lib.ds_status,
solic_lib.ds_usuario,
solic_lib.dt data_atualizacao,

ap_res.ds_status,
ap_res.ds_usuario,
ap_res.dt data_atualizacao,

dig_res.ds_status,
dig_res.ds_usuario,
dig_res.dt data_atualizacao,

teste_res.ds_status,
teste_res.ds_usuario,
teste_res.dt data_atualizacao,

teste_res1.ds_status,
teste_res1.ds_usuario,
teste_res1.dt data_atualizacao,

teste_res2.ds_status,
teste_res2.ds_usuario,
teste_res2.dt data_atualizacao

from

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 10
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) solic_lib,

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
max (decode(a.ie_exame_bloqueado,'S','Bloqueado', decode(a.ie_exame_bloqueado,'R','Repetição', decode(obter_se_recoleta_proc_etapa(a.nr_prescricao,a.nr_seq_prescricao,a.nr_sequencia),'S','Recoleta','')))) as ds_exame_bloqueado,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 20
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) ap_res,

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 25
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) dig_res,

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 30
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.ie_exame_bloqueado <> 'R'
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) teste_res,

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 35
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.ie_exame_bloqueado <> 'R'
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) teste_res1,

---

(select
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt_entrada,
' '||e.nm_unidade nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica nm_medico,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90) ds_status,
a.nm_usuario,
b.ds_usuario,
max (a.nr_sequencia) as nr,
max (TO_CHAR(c.DT_PRESCRICAO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) as npp,
max (to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,('dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))) as dt,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90) ds_motivo_recoleta,
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia TUBETE,
n.nr_seq_exame
FROM
prescr_proc_etapa a,
usuario b,
prescr_medica c,
prescr_procedimento d,
atendimento_paciente_v e,
pessoa_fisica g,
medico m,
exame_laboratorio n,
material_exame_lab o
WHERE
upper(a.nm_usuario) = upper(b.nm_usuario(+))
and  a.nr_prescricao IN (87935)
and a.ie_etapa = 40
and d.cd_motivo_baixa = 1
and a.ie_exame_bloqueado <> 'R'
and a.nr_prescricao       = c.nr_prescricao
and c.nr_prescricao       = d.nr_prescricao
and e.nr_atendimento      = c.nr_atendimento
and c.cd_medico           = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and m.cd_pessoa_fisica    = g.cd_pessoa_fisica
and d.nr_seq_exame        = n.nr_seq_exame
-- AND ( ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) OR ( c.DT_PRESCRICAO BETWEEN :dt_inicial AND :dt_final ) )
AND d.ie_horario_susp = 'N'
and o.nr_sequencia        = obter_mat_exame_lab_prescr(d.nr_prescricao, d.nr_sequencia, 1)
and  a.nr_seq_prescricao  = 1
group by
n.NM_EXAME,
e.nm_paciente,
a.nr_prescricao,
e.ds_idade,
e.ds_sexo,
e.NR_PRONTUARIO,
e.DS_ANOS_MESES,
e.DT_NASCIMENTO,
e.nr_atendimento,
e.ds_tipo_atendimento,
e.ds_convenio,
TO_CHAR(e.dt_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
' '||e.nm_unidade,
e.cd_unidade,
e.ds_setor_atendimento,
m.nr_crm,
g.nm_pessoa_fisica,
a.ie_etapa,
a.nr_seq_prescricao,
substr(Obter_Valor_Dominio_Status_LIS(a.ie_etapa),1,90),
a.nm_usuario,
substr(lab_obter_desc_motivo_recoleta(d.nr_seq_recoleta),1,90),
'00' || d.nr_prescricao || 'M' || O.nr_sequencia,
n.nr_seq_exame,
b.ds_usuario) teste_res2

where

```
  solic_lib.nr_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_prescricao
```

and   solic_lib.nr_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_prescricao

and   ap_res.nr_prescricao        = solic_lib.nr_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_prescricao        = dig_res.nr_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_prescricao        = teste_res.nr_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_prescricao        = teste_res1.nr_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_prescricao        = teste_res2.nr_prescricao

and   dig_res.nr_prescricao       = solic_lib.nr_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_prescricao       = ap_res.nr_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_prescricao       = teste_res.nr_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_prescricao       = teste_res1.nr_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_prescricao       = teste_res2.nr_prescricao

and   teste_res.nr_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_prescricao

and   teste_res1.nr_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_prescricao

and   teste_res2.nr_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_prescricao

---

and   solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao

and   ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao        = solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao        = dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao        = teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao        = teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao
and   ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao        = teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao

and   dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao       = solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao       = ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao       = teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao       = teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao
and   dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao       = teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao

and   teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao

and   teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao

and   teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao     = solic_lib.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao     = ap_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao     = dig_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res.nr_seq_prescricao
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_prescricao     = teste_res1.nr_seq_prescricao

---

and   solic_lib.nr_seq_exame          = ap_res.nr_seq_exame
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_exame          = dig_res.nr_seq_exame
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_exame          = teste_res.nr_seq_exame
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_exame          = teste_res1.nr_seq_exame
and   solic_lib.nr_seq_exame          = teste_res2.nr_seq_exame

and   ap_res.nr_seq_exame             = solic_lib.nr_seq_exame
and   ap_res.nr_seq_exame             = dig_res.nr_seq_exame
and   ap_res.nr_seq_exame             = teste_res.nr_seq_exame
and   ap_res.nr_seq_exame             = teste_res1.nr_seq_exame
and   ap_res.nr_seq_exame             = teste_res2.nr_seq_exame

and   dig_res.nr_seq_exame            = solic_lib.nr_seq_exame
and   dig_res.nr_seq_exame            = ap_res.nr_seq_exame
and   dig_res.nr_seq_exame            = teste_res.nr_seq_exame
and   dig_res.nr_seq_exame            = teste_res1.nr_seq_exame
and   dig_res.nr_seq_exame            = teste_res2.nr_seq_exame

and   teste_res.nr_seq_exame          = solic_lib.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res.nr_seq_exame          = ap_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res.nr_seq_exame          = dig_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res.nr_seq_exame          = teste_res1.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res.nr_seq_exame          = teste_res2.nr_seq_exame

and   teste_res1.nr_seq_exame         = solic_lib.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_exame         = ap_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_exame         = dig_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_exame         = teste_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res1.nr_seq_exame         = teste_res2.nr_seq_exame

and   teste_res2.nr_seq_exame         = solic_lib.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_exame         = ap_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_exame         = dig_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_exame         = teste_res.nr_seq_exame
and   teste_res2.nr_seq_exame         = teste_res1.nr_seq_exame

ORDER BY 11, 1, 7

Answer (score -1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue modelo em anexo com imagem de como deveria ficar o resultado do SCRIPT.